# Definition of Norm of an Ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I need to prove $(23,\alpha-10)$ is a prime ideal in $Z[\alpha]/(\alpha^3-\alpha-1)$. I want to show that $Norm(23,\alpha-10)$ is a prime number, thus proving it is a prime as we are in a Dedekind domain. Can anyone help me to compute the ideal norm?

Also, in particular, I know that for a PID, $R$, $Norm(I)$, $I\in R$ is given by the generator conjugate's products. Can anyone help me to get the connection between this definition and $Norm(I)=|R/I|$?

Comment: This connection is not going to help you, I suggest trying to compute the size of the quotient directly.  Remember, the quotient here will look like a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ as an abelian group.

Comment: Are there any other ways to show this is a prime ideal?

Comment: You need to compute the size of the quotient R/I, the connection I am referring to is the relationship with norms of principal ideals. Consider the ring as 3 copies of the integers indexed by powers of $\alpha$ as I mention above and this is just an exercise in group theory

Comment: Is it $p^3$? If we quotient with $(p,a-10), we get $ Z_p\times Z_p\times Z_p$ Thus size is p^3?

Comment: No it is not, if it were to be $p^3$ then you certainly would not have started with a prime ideal.  Note that, just because $p$ is an integer does not mean it gives a nonzero entry in each summand.   I've answered below with a description of the identification I outlined in my comment, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ${\rm disc}(x^3-x-1) = -23$ is squarefree, the ring of integers of the field $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ is $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ (do you know why?), so the way an ideal $(p) = p\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ decomposes in $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ matches how $x^3 - x - 1$ decomposes in $(\mathbf Z/(p))[x]$.   Is this a result you've heard of already?  Since $x^3 - x - 1 \equiv (x -3)(x - 10)^2 \bmod 23$, we have the prime ideal factorization $(23) = (23, \alpha-3)(23,\alpha-10)^2$ where both prime ideals $(23, \alpha-3)$ and $(23,\alpha-10)$ have norm $23^1$ since both irreducible factors of $x^3 - x - 1 \bmod 23$ have degree $1$.

More generally, the Dedekind--Kummer theorem says that in *every* number field $K$ with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic *integer*  generating $K$ over $\mathbf Q$ then (even if $\mathcal O_K \not= \mathbf Z[\alpha]$) for each prime $p$ not dividing $[\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$, the way $(p) = p\mathcal O_K$ decomposes into prime ideals in $\mathcal O_K$ resembles how $f(x)$ decomposes in $(\mathbf Z/(p))[x]$ where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q$ (necessarily $f(x)$ is monic in $\mathbf Z[x]$): if
$$
f(x) \equiv \pi_1(x)^{e_1} \cdots \pi_g(x)^{e_g} \bmod p
$$
with irreducible $\pi_i(x)$ in $(\mathbf Z/(p))[x]$ then
$$
p\mathbf Z[\alpha] = \mathfrak p_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak p_g^{e_g}
$$
where $\mathfrak p_i = (p,\pi_i(\alpha))$ and the norm of $\mathfrak p_i$ is $p^{\deg \pi_i}$. (Although $\pi_i(x)$ is defined as a polynomial in $(\mathbf Z/(p))[x]$, the ideal $(p,\pi_i(\alpha))$ is well-defined because the ambiguity of the lift of $\pi_i(x)$ to $\mathbf Z[x]$ is washed out in the ideal $(p,\pi_i(\alpha))$ since the ideal contains $p$.) See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf) for further details.

Your description of the norm of a principal ideal as a product of conjugates of a generators is not the right way to think about the norm as a foundational concept. You should define the field norm ${\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha)$ of an element $\alpha$ in a number field $K$ as $\det(m_\alpha)$ where $m_\alpha \colon K \to K$ is the multiplication-by-$\alpha$ map viewed as a $\mathbf Q$-linear map.  That this definition for ${\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha)$ agrees with the "product of conjugates" viewpoint is [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf) (see Theorem 5.9 and Corollary 5.15 to relate minimal and characteristic polynomials of an element in a finite extension field). For every nonzero ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $\mathcal O_K$, the ideal norm ${\rm N}(\mathfrak a)$ of $\mathfrak a$ is defined to to be the index $[\mathcal O_K:\mathfrak a]$. The compatibility between these two concepts of norm (of an element and an ideal) occurs in the case where  $\mathfrak a = (\alpha)$ is a principal ideal for some nonzero $\alpha \in \cal O_K$, where the compatibility is ${\rm N}((\alpha)) = |{\rm N}_{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha)|$. That formula is a special case of Theorem 5.15 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/modulesoverPID.pdf) by taking $M = \mathcal O_K$, $M' = \alpha\mathcal O_K$, and letting $(c_{ij})$ be the matrix expressing a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $\alpha\mathcal O_K$ in terms of a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $\mathcal O_K$.  Moreover, that also gives an approach to computing the norm
of an arbitrary nonzero ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $\mathcal O_K$: ${\rm N}(\mathfrak a) = |\det(c_{ij})|$ where $(c_{ij})$ is the matrix describing a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $\mathfrak a$ in terms of a $\mathbf Z$-basis of $\mathcal O_K$.
A completely different method of computing ${\rm N}(\mathfrak a)$ by using a field norm for $K(T)/\mathbf Q(T)$, due to Kronecker, is described in the top MO answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26549/is-there-much-difference-between-kroneckers-and-dedekinds-methods-in-algebraic).

Answer (score 0):

Let's label $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\langle\alpha^3-\alpha-1\rangle$ and $I=\langle 23,\alpha-10 \rangle$.  Then we can identify (as abelian groups)
$$R\cong \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$
via the map $x+y\alpha+z\alpha^2\mapsto (x,y,z)$. Note that this map identifies (again as abelian groups)
$$I\cong \langle(23, 0, 0), (-10, 1, 0), (-100, 0, 1)\rangle$$
(you should check this to be sure for yourself!).  At this point the quotient (as an abelian group) on the right hand side of this identification is clear, it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$.