# Showing that $R$ is a Dedekind ring, determine all prime ideals of norm at most 30 and $R^*$ is a infinite group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a zero of the polynomial $x^3-x-1$, and $R = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Show that $R$ is a Dedekind ring, and determine all prime ideals of norm at most 30 in $R$. Show also that the unit group $R^∗$ is infinite.

I have just learned the Kummur-Dedekind theorem so I think I have to use that for computing the primes but I don't know how to do that concretely and the first and last part are just unknown how to approach it.

Comment: Can you please provide the statement of the theorem that was given to you in class?

Comment: The extension $K = \Bbb Q[\alpha]$ is monogenic, as in your other today's [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783055/mathbbz-sqrt3d-dedekind-if-and-only-if-d-is-square-free-and-satisfi), this shows $R$ is a Dedekind ring. For the last question, you might have had some form of [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem) (of course, manual computation is also an option).

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I have not encountered that Dirichlet theorem. Could you do perhaps one or two computation and I think I can try to do the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is the discriminant of a $\Bbb Z$-submodule in $K = \Bbb Q(\alpha)$ (and how to compute it)? Do you know the formula quoted in the OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497380/discriminant-of-ideal-equals-its-norm-squared-times-the-discriminant-of-the-ring) (it is true for any number field, not just quadratic ones as in there)? Compute the discriminant of $\{1,\alpha, \alpha^2\}$; can one now conclude that $O_K = \Bbb Z[\alpha]$ and $R$ is a Dedekind ring?
2. Do you know why 2.1) the norm of a prime ideal $\frak{p}$ is $p^k$, where $p \in \frak{p} \cap \Bbb Z$ is the unique rational integer prime in $\frak{p}$, and 2.2) all such prime ideals divide $(p)$?

Then you'll have to decompose the ideals $(p)$ for prime $p=2,\ldots, 29$ via Kummer—Dedekind. Mathematica says that the nontrivial factorizations of $x^3-x-1\! \mod p$ occur at $p=5,7,11,17,19$, [$23$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904799/definition-of-norm-of-an-ideal). Starting from $5$, you should disregard the cubic factors (as the corresponding ideals will have norm at least $125$), and the quadratic factors starting from $7$. I can count $9$ prime ideals of norm $\le 30$ (hope this isn't wrong).

3. $\alpha$ is a unit of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ — why? Then you can prove the fact that $\{x^n\!\! \mod x^3-x-1\} \subset \Bbb Q[x]$ are distinct for $n \ge 0$ (via induction); for this specific polynomial it will be easy.

**Edit.** (09 Oct 2023).

2.2. If $p \in \frak p$, then $(p) \subset \frak p$. Then apply the fact that for fractional ideals $M_1, M_2$, *"$M_1 \subset M_2$"* is equivalent to *"$M_1 M_2^{-1}$ is an integral ideal"* (this kind of situation is called [antitone Galois correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Antitone_Galois_connection) between the corresponding posets).

1. As in the closed question, it'll be sufficient to prove that $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is integrally closed in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, which means that **every** number in $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2 \in \Bbb Q[\alpha]$ that has a monic minimal polynomial with integer coefficients must have $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z$. Do you know how to construct the minimal polynomial of such a number? (Hint: consider the matrix of multiplication by $\alpha$ in $\Bbb Q$-basis $1,\alpha, \alpha^2$. What do you know about charpoly and minpoly of algebraic numbers?)

Maybe some kind of a less computational method was meant for 1., but I don't know what's covered in your syllabus.

Comment: 1. We have not learned what the discriminant is. We will do that in the next chapter I saw. So I guess we can not use it right now.
2.1 Yes I do know that
2.2 I did not know that one yet

Comment: @Whateverittakes Added a section under "Edit".

Comment: the way to do 1 was to conclude that all the primes are regular and therefore Dedekind